# fp - How to keep running sum in variable?

Tags: fp

I have this code in my LaTeX:

```
\FPset{totalHours}{0}

\newcommand{\entry}[5]{
    \FPeval{totalHours}{(totalHours)+#5}
    #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 \\
}
```

Where `\entry` is meant to be an entry in a time log. The 5th argument is a number representing the number of hours in that entry. I want to keep a running total of the hours in a variable I can print later on, `totalHours`.

This seems to do the `\FPeval` but then `totalHours` gets reset to `0` by the next time I write `\entry`. What is the correct way to keep a running total? Thanks.

Comment: Is totalHours a counter or normal variable? Entry seems to end up in a tabular construction. Cells in a tabular form a group, so if `\FPeval` is storing the value in a normal macro (behind the scenes), then the new value never leaves the cell. See if the fp package can store it globally instead, then it survives the grouping from the cell.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be setting the `\entry` inside a `tabular`; the scope of command definitions within a `tabular` cell is limited to that cell as it forms a group. And, since the [`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) evaluations are essentially macro definitions, all calculations are lost after setting the row.

One way around this would be to make the definition global after evaluation via

```
\xdef\totalHours{\totalHours}
```

Here is a complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
  \FPeval{totalHours}{totalHours+#5}% Add to totalHours
  \xdef\totalHours{\totalHours}% Make definition \global
  #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 \\% Set entry
}

\begin{document}

\FPset{totalHours}{0}

\begin{tabular}{ *{5}{r} }
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & totalHours \\
  \hline
  \entry{A}{B}{C}{D}{1.1}
  \entry{A}{B}{C}{D}{2.2}
  \entry{A}{B}{C}{D}{3.3}
  \entry{A}{B}{C}{D}{4.4}
  \entry{A}{B}{C}{D}{5.5}
\end{tabular}

Total hours: \FPround{\totalHours}{\totalHours}{1}\totalHours

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there are better methods.

I suggest to use `expl3` features, that also avoid risking to clobber commands.

Taking [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333986/4427) as base:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zerofpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:c { g_egreg_#1_fp }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { g_egreg_#1_fp }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\updatefpvar}{mm}
 {
  \fp_gset:cn { g_egreg_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
  \updatefpvar{totalHours}{\usefpvar{totalHours}+#5}% Add to totalHours
  #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 \\% Set entry
}

\begin{document}

\zerofpvar{totalHours}

\begin{tabular}{ *{5}{r} }
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & totalHours \\
  \hline
  \entry{A}{B}{C}{D}{1.1}
  \entry{A}{B}{C}{D}{2.2}
  \entry{A}{B}{C}{D}{3.3}
  \entry{A}{B}{C}{D}{4.4}
  \entry{A}{B}{C}{D}{5.5}
\end{tabular}

Total hours: \usefpvar{totalHours}

\end{document}
```

[image]