# Why doesn't the fp package work inside tabulars and how do I get around that?

Tags: tables, environments, fp

I want to add sums while writing tabular (tabularx) lines. For this I have written a command to emit individual lines, but all the `\FPxxx` commands fail to work from within the tabular environment.

I boiled this down to this MRE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fp}

\FPset\x{2}
\FPadd\x\x{7}

\begin{document}
\Huge

x = \x

\begin{tabular}{l}
\FPadd\x\x{100}text
\end{tabular}

x = \x\\(should be 109)

\end{document}
```

This results in the following output:

[image: x = 9.00000]

As you can see, the first `\FPadd` worked, but the second one inside the environment fails.

**Why and how can I work around that?**

Comment: a tabular cell is a group so it is like surrounding the computation by `{...}` and the value restores at the end of the cell.

Comment: Table cells for a group. You can add `\xdef\x{\x}` after the computation. Maybe `fp` supports a global setting, but I have no experience with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fp - How to keep running sum in variable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333981/fp-how-to-keep-running-sum-in-variable) See also [Why does the result of FPeval disappear after a `&`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455569/82917).